# How to make Player consistently jump *to* a specific target rather than *towards* it?

Tags: unity, physics

I'm trying to make it so if my player hits "E" then they jump precisely to a specific target. The current code results in player jumping *towards* the target but not really making it there.

I've tried adjusting forceMultiply and ForceMode and adding an offset but I just can't get a result that simply consistently launches the player's rigidbody `rb` towards the `anchorPoint` position.

The code I have is:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        tryGrabbing = true;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (tryGrabbing)
    {
        rb.AddForce(anchorPoint.transform.position * forceMultiply, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Think of your player character as a projectile, and consult [past Q&A about determining the launch velocity for a ballistic projectile to strike its target](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114547/39518)

Comment: You should also get in the habit of doing a quick back-of-napkin [dimensional analysis](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/194550/39518) on physics code, to ensure your units make sense. Multiplying an absolute position by a scaling constant will *never* turn that position into an impulse - so the AddForce code you've shown here has no hope of doing what you meant it to. To make an impulse, we'd need a displacement (a *difference* between two positions), a time window, and a mass, in order to get a value in Newton-seconds (kg m / s) that makes sense to use as an impulse.

Comment: Hi @DMGregory , do you have advice for making Player jump at the Target front-on, rather than on top of it? Here is an image of what I mean. https://i.imgur.com/z9CNk9y.png Is this a matter of changing what formula is employed?

Comment: Aim at a lower target point, or choose a lower time value (increased launch velocity) or less gravity. This will flatten the arc so you hit your apex at/after the target rather than before descending to the target.